# How can I split data in an input field using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form with an option to add a post code (or zip code for US readers), and I want to split the input into the following format: XXX XXXX.

I am using the following JavaScript to split it into threes (XXX XXX XXX); however, I would like to split the first three characters from the second four characters. How can I do that?

```
var ecode = document.getElementById("postcode");
ecode.oninput = function() {
    var format = ecode.value.split(" ").join("");
    if (format.length > 0) {
        format = format.match(new RegExp('.{1, 3}','g')).join(" ");
    }
    this.value = format;
};
```

Comment: show html snippet with id `postcode`

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest, The issue has been resolved for me and I don't think showing the HTML snippet is necessary. It's just an <input> tag with an ID of postcode. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do this:

```
var format = ecode.value.replace(/ /g, "");
ecode.value = format.substr(0, 3) + " " + format.substr(3, 4);
```

Note this will discard anything past the 7 first non-whitespace characters.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. The only thing is that when I use the backspace to delete it, it only removes the last four. Any ideas why?

Comment: I would recommend that you put this code in the onchange event. Modifying the text while the user is typing may not be very friendly.

Comment: Perfeito! Thanks once again. I used onchange instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace for the first three characters.

```js
var format = '',
    i;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    format += 'X';
    console.log(format.replace(/.../, '$& '));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```